# How to debug Apache when server is not reachable and no error is thrown?

Tags: server, 20.04, apache2, debugging

I'm trying to use a new server (VPS) for my website. I bought a new server and installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it.

After that, I logged in as root and start

- Installing Apache, PHP, MySQL
- Pulling the code base (using `git`)
- Installing needed packages (using `composer`)
- Replacing `AllowOverride None` with `AllowOverride ALL`
- Enabling `rewrite` and restarting apache2

All done as well. Noted that, in the beginning, when I was configuring the Apache, I could see the Apache's sample page as well when I was entering the server's IP in the browser.

But now, after doing the rest of the steps, now the website is not reachable anymore. The sad part is there is nothing throwing inside the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` nor `access.log` files.

I've even disabled `ufw` to make sure it's not what caused the server to be not reachable. Here is the server I'm talking about:

```
https://152.89.45.83/
```

Any idea how can I debug it?

Comment: If nothing is being recorded in the access log, that may mean that Apache is not running. If there are accesses but no errors, then the PHP site that you installed is capturing the request and (potentially) failing silently. If the issue is in the PHP, consider changing the logging level to have every error and warning displayed in the return HTML 

Comment: @matigo Yeah there was an script inside `.htaccess` that was redirecting `http` to `https` and I wasn't able to understand it .. You know, there is not SSL even installed on the server. Anyway I got the issue and trying to fix it. Thx